# Finding number of occurrence of characters in a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose the string is "this is string"

I have to define a table valued function to output the result:

```
+------+-------+
| char | count |
+------+-------+
|      |   3   |
| t    |   2   |
| h    |   1   |
| i    |   3   |
| s    |   3   |
| a    |   1   |
| r    |   1   |
| n    |   1   |
|  g   |   1   |
+------+-------+
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Please post your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION CountCharacterOccurences(@str nvarchar(max))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    WITH Nums(n) -- Generate numbers from 1 to LEN(@str)
    AS(
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1
        FROM Nums
        WHERE n+1 <= LEN(@str)
    )
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(@str, n, 1) AS char, 
        COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM Nums
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(@str, n, 1)
```

Usage

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(max)
SET @str = 'this is a string';

SELECT * FROM  CountCharacterOccurences(@str)
```

Returns

```
char count
    3
a   1
g   1
h   1
i   3
n   1
r   1
s   3
t   2
```

Comment: nice! could you please explain ,it would be helpful... I am not familiar with some syntax like 'WITH' after return statement

Comment: The 'WITH' statement is a [Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) (CTE). this query uses a [Recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfCharCount] (@String varchar(max))

Returns Table

As
Return

    Select Char,Count=count(*) 
     From (
            Select Char = Substring(a.b, v.number+1, 1) 
             From (select @String b) a
             Join master..spt_values v on v.number < len(a.b) where v.type = 'P'
          ) A
     Group By Char


-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udfCharCount]('this is a string')
```

Returns

```
Char    Count
        3
a       1
g       1
h       1
i       3
n       1
r       1
s       3
t       2
```

Comment: Thanks. But,I am having trouble to understand some of it,as I am newbie in SQL Server

Comment: @Zahid just powered down for the day.  On my phone.  In the AM I will provide a narrative.

Comment: Oh,that would be nice and helpful

Comment: `spt_values` is an undocumented system table, and is unsupported in recent versions of SQL server

Comment: @Mono wow.  Thanks for the tip.  I'm still on 2012.  Will make the adjustment.